# Python Numpy : How to convert text file with pair of comma separate floats to multidimensional 'ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am new to numpy and i need to convert text file with data

> 219062.60893,395935.54879 219332.52719,395961.82402 219301.47465,395688.32278 219036.33371,395677.57382
>   218761.63814,395494.84155 219164.12686,395438.70811 219086.49551,395244.03255 218758.05515,395308.52630

to a numpy ndarray of

[[[219062.60893,395935.54879],[219332.52719,395961.82402],[219301.47465,395688.32278],[219036.33371,395677.57382]],
    [[218761.63814,395494.84155],[219164.12686,395438.70811],[219086.49551,395244.03255],[218758.05515,395308.52630]]]

what i tried is this

```
 textLineArray = np.loadtxt(filePath, str, None, None, None, 0, None, False,0,'bytes',None)
```

gives me

```
[['219062.60893,395935.54879' '219332.52719,395961.82402'
 '219301.47465,395688.32278' '219036.33371,395677.57382'],
['218761.63814,395494.84155' '219164.12686,395438.70811'
 '219086.49551,395244.03255' '218758.05515,395308.52630']]
```

and after further spiting with space

```
spaceTextLineArray = np.char.split(textLineArray, ' ', maxsplit=None)
```

I get this

```
[[list(['219062.60893,395935.54879']) list(['219332.52719,395961.82402'])
 list(['219301.47465,395688.32278']) list(['219036.33371,395677.57382'])],[list(['218761.63814,395494.84155']) list(['219164.12686,395438.70811'])
 list(['219086.49551,395244.03255']) list(['218758.05515,395308.52630'])]]
```

quite their but not exactly their don't know how to get-rid of single quotes

Comment: You can try [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have any code to show what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Please dig into np.array() func. hint : "string1 string2".split(" ") --> ['string1','string2']

Comment: @squareskittles thanks, I have edited the post and added some code with what i archived.

Comment: @ManishArote Have you tried to do as I wrote you in my answer?

Comment: @ManishArote My outputs looks like what you were looking for. I’m wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First solution

Try this code:

```
import numpy as np

data = []
with open('data.txt') as my_file:      
    for line in my_file:  
        data.append([list(map(float ,x.split(','))) for x in line.split(' ')])
arr_data = np.array(data)
```

and `arr_data` will contain your numpy array:

```
array([[[219062.60893, 395935.54879],
        [219332.52719, 395961.82402],
        [219301.47465, 395688.32278],
        [219036.33371, 395677.57382]],

       [[218761.63814, 395494.84155],
        [219164.12686, 395438.70811],
        [219086.49551, 395244.03255],
        [218758.05515, 395308.5263 ]]])
```

Brief explanation:

1. Read your file line by line
2. Format and store one line data in a list
3. Convert list to numpy array

---

### Second solution

Another solution, without external for-loops, which produces the same results:

```
arr_data = [[list(map(float, a.split(','))) for a in s] for s in np.loadtxt('myData.csv', dtype=str)]
```

## Comparison of Execution Times

I used a file like yours format, with 5000 lines, and the results obtained are the following:

- First Solution:

  `# 41.4 ms ± 4.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`
- Second Solution:

  `# 84.6 ms ± 6.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

The first solution I proposed to you seems to be about twice as fast.

---

### Extra

If instead you have a *standard csv format*, and you want to upload them directly to a numpy array, you can do so:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
arr_data = genfromtxt('file_data.csv',delimiter=',')
```

and `my_data` will contain your numpy array.

Comment: It's not a standard csv format, it is a line delimited format each line denoted with 4 comma separated coordinated (x,y) for a polygon. I want to do it in numpy way directly and not with the for loop.

Comment: I updated my answer, adding a solution that gets the expected result in a single line of code, without external for-loops. @ManishArote

Comment: I also added a comparison on the execution times of the two solutions I proposed to you. @ManishArote